# Provisioning profile “match x” doesn't include signing certificate “Apple Distribution: Company (ID)” when using fastlane match

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, fastlane, fastlane-match

This error was encountered while trying to build one of our apps that had signing via fastlane match set up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some googling I found [these steps](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13079#issuecomment-412299530). The long and the short of it is that if you generate a signing certificate via fastlane cert and/or Xcode automatic signing it will conflict with the cert needed by fastlane match. To resolve this you should backup and delete your distribution certs and then rely on fastlane match to generate them for you.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error. In my case, I had to delete the old ones from my macs Keychain. After that fastlane did its magic.

Answer (score -4):

I solved this issue by adding a device to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list

to get a device's udid plug it into your computer and Xcode will tell you what it is (it's not on the device afaict).